# Sbt Package a scala project

Tags: java, scala, jar, sbt

I want to create a runnable jar file from a Scala project. I install sbt on window 7. I create a file hw.scala :

```
object Hi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!")
}
```

File built.sbt ( in the same directory )

```
    lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
      settings(
        name := "hello",
        version := "1.0",
        scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
      )
```

When I run "sbt run", it displays the result. After that, I run "sbt compile" then "sbt package". However when I run

```
java -jar target\scala-2.11\hello_2.11-1.0.jar
```

The consonle notice the error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Could some one help me ?

Comment: I solve my problem. I add sbt assembly, which I followed the guide : https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly. When I run "sbt assembly", the jar file can be run

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. I add sbt assembly, which I followed the link https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly : . When I run "sbt assembly", the jar file can be run